# Javascript. Evento click se ejecuta 4 veces

Tags: javascript, eventos, click

Estoy haciendo un trabajo de un curso que estoy haciendo de JavaScript. Le puse un eventlistener a un botón y por alguna razón que no logro encontrar, el código dentro de el se ejecuta 4 veces.

Se supone que es un juego de colores en el que con javascript le doy colores a unos cuadrados creados con html.
Perdón si falta alguna información necesaria, es mi primera vez preguntando en stackoverflow

```javascript
let botonstart = document.querySelector("#play");

botonstart.addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".message").textContent = ""
    document.querySelector(".titulo").style.color = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
    document.querySelector("#play").innerHTML = "Restart"
    btndif.disabled = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < numsquare; i++) {
        colors.push(colorRandom()); // se guarda el color, que se genera aleatoriamente en el metodo, dentro del arreglo
        square[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i]; //se asigna el color al cuadrado
        square[i].addEventListener("click", changeColors)
    }
    pickColor(); //se llama al metodo pickcolor para selecionar aleatoriamente el color a adivinar
    document.querySelector("span").textContent = pickedColor;
});
```

Código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Color Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container text-center">
    <h1 class="titulo">The Great <span class="colorDisplay"></span> Guessing Game</h1>
    <br>
  </div>

  <div id="div-message">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">

        <div class="navbar">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton"
              data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dificultad
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="facil">Facil</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="normal">Normal</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="dificil">Dificil</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="demente">Demente</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="message text-center">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="square" id="sq0"></div>
        <div class="square" id="sq1"></div>
        <div class="square" id="sq2"></div>
        <div class="square" id="sq3"></div>
        <div class="square" id="sq4"></div>
        <div class="square" id="sq5"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="square" id="sq6"></div>
        <div class="square" id="sq7"></div>
        <div class="square" id="sq8"></div>
        <div class="square" id="sq9"></div>
        <div class="square" id="sq10"></div>
        <div class="square" id="sq11"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="square" id="sq12"></div>
        <div class="square" id="sq13"></div>
        <div class="square" id="sq14"></div>
        <div class="square" id="sq15"></div>
        <div class="square" id="sq16"></div>
        <div class="square" id="sq17"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="square" id="sq18"></div>
        <div class="square" id="sq19"></div>
        <div class="square" id="sq20"></div>
        <div class="square" id="sq21"></div>
        <div class="square" id="sq22"></div>
        <div class="square" id="sq23"></div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <br>
    <button type="button" id="play" class="btn btn-success">Play!</button>
  </div>

  </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/eeb28b5c66.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Código de JavaScript:

```
let square = document.querySelectorAll(".square"); //arreglo de "cuadrados"
let colors = []; //arreglo para guardar colores utilizados por los cuadrados
let pickedColor; //variable para guardar el color seleccionado para jugar
let flag = false;
let dif = document.querySelector(".dropdown-menu").children
let numsquare = 24;
let btndif = document.getElementById("dropdownMenuButton")
let start = true;
let botonstart = document.querySelector("#play");

for (let i = 0; i < dif.length; i++) {
    dif[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (this.textContent == "Facil") {
            dificultad(3, "square1", "square");
            numsquare = 3;
        } else if (this.textContent == "Normal") {
            dificultad(6, "square1", "square");
            numsquare = 6;

        } else if (this.textContent == "Dificil") {
            dificultad(12, "square", "square1");
            numsquare = 12;

        } else {
            dificultad(24, "square", "square1");
            numsquare = 24;
        }

    })

    botonstart.addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.querySelector(".message").textContent = ""
        document.querySelector(".titulo").style.color = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
        document.querySelector("#play").innerHTML = "Restart"
        btndif.disabled = true;
        for (let i = 0; i < numsquare; i++) {
            colors.push(colorRandom()); // se guarda el color, que se genera aleatoriamente en el metodo, dentro del arreglo

            square[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i]; //se asigna el color al cuadrado

            square[i].addEventListener("click", changeColors)

        }

        pickColor(); //se llama al metodo pickcolor para selecionar aleatoriamente el color a adivinar

        document.querySelector("span").textContent = pickedColor;
     
       

    });

    function colorRandom() {

        let color = "rgb(";

        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // el for da 3 vueltas, para cumplic con el codigo rgb


            if (i == 2) {

                color += (Math.round(Math.random() * 256 - 1).toString()).concat(")"); //se genera aleatoriamente un numero entre 0 y 255 y luego se concatena en la variable local color

            } else {

                color += (Math.round(Math.random() * 256 - 1).toString()).concat(", "); //se genera aleatoriamente un numero entre 0 y 255 y luego se concatena en la variable local color

            }
        }
        return color;
    }

    function pickColor() {
        pickedColor = "";
        let index = Math.round(Math.random() * colors.length - 1);
        if (index < 0)
            index = 1;

        pickedColor = colors[index]; //se elige aleatoriamente el color a partir del arreglo que contiene los colores usados por los cuadrados
        colors = [];
    }

    function changeColors() { //se crea un evento para cada cuadrado

        let clickedColor = this.style.backgroundColor; //se asigna el color del cuadrado cliqueado dentro de la variable
        if (clickedColor == pickedColor) {
            for (let i = 0; i < square.length; i++) { //si coincide con el seleccionado para jugar, todos los cuadrados tendrán el mismo color

                square[i].style.backgroundColor = pickedColor;
                document.querySelector("h1").style.color = pickedColor;

            }
            document.querySelector(".message").textContent = "Correct!"
            btndif.disabled = false;
            botonstart.innerHTML = "Play Again?"
        } else {

            this.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(35, 35, 35)"; //si no coincide, el cuadrado cliqueado será de ese color
            document.querySelector(".message").textContent = "Try Again"
        }

    }

    function dificultad(squares, classuse, classdel) {

        for (let i = squares; i < square.length; i++) {

            square[i].classList.add("hide")
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < squares; i++) {
            square[i].classList.remove("hide")
            square[i].classList.remove(classdel)
            square[i].classList.add(classuse)

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Te sugiero colocar también tu HTML. Es probable que se esté propagando el evento y para eso debes de usar el parametro de la funcion del evento y ejecutar el metodo stopPropagation()

Comment: Que sería `numsquare`?

Comment: Como dice el primer comentario, agrega tambien el HTML y toda la función JS respectiva

Comment: @DarkVaderM ahi coloqué el codigo en GitHub, pues no pude formatearlo para que quedase prolijo. https://github.com/leaa98/colorgame/tree/main/colorGame

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera es el numero de cuadrados que debe recorrer el arreglo y darles un color al azar utlizando la función colorRandom()

Comment: @AndresGardiol ahí coloque el codigo en gitHub

Comment: Hola, para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida te recomiendo que leas [ask]. Tienes que agregar el código en la pregunta misma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un bucle `for` en el que en cada iteración se ejecuta la línea sentencia:

```
botonstart.addEventListener("click", function(){ ... })
```

Por lo que estás añadiendo N veces un "event listener" al botón start.